# How to use Email::Mime with sendmail

Tags: perl, mime-types, sendmail

I am trying to send HTML email using a script. I will have to use native unix things and `Email::Mime` since those are the only thing I found installed in the box i am stuck with. I am creating a `Email::Mime` message and sending it to sendmail.

But i keep getting Error: **No recipient addresses found in header**
I have seen other RUBY scripts using `sendmail` so that works for this box.

Can someone help me with what I might be doing wrong in the below snippet?

```
sub send_mail(){

use MIME::QuotedPrint;
use HTML::Entities;
use IO::All;
use Email::MIME;

# multipart message
my @parts = (
    Email::MIME->create(
        attributes => {
            content_type => "text/html",
            disposition  => "attachment",
            encoding     => "quoted-printable",
            charset      => "US-ASCII",
        },
        body_str => "Hello there!",
    ),
);

my $email = Email::MIME->create(
    header_str => [
        To => 'abc@xxx.com',
        From => 'abc@xxx.com',
        Subject => "Test Email",
    ],
    parts      => [@parts],
);

# die $email->as_string;
# die YAML::XS::Dump(\%mail);

open(MAIL, "|/usr/sbin/sendmail -t");

print MAIL $email;

close (MAIL);

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could just use [Email::Sender::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Sender::Manual::QuickStart). It's designed to work with Email::MIME and it defaults to using sendmail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print MAIL $email;
```

should be

```
print MAIL $email->as_string;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if your E-Mail server requires authentication (which most do of course), you need to specify  a SMTP session:

```
$transport = EMail::Sender::Transport::SMTP::Persistent->new({
  # host, port, ssl, etc
})
```

Furthermore, I think you don't actually need to create the content as an own MIME-content.
I did use something similar to this in my own work:

```
$email = Email::MIME->Create(
  header_str => [ ... ],
  body_str => $message,
  attributes => {
    charset => 'UTF-8',
    encoding => 'base64',
    content_type => 'text/html',
  }
)
```

After sending your mail via `sendmail($email, { transport => $transport })`, you need to close the session through `$transport->disconnect`.

For your application you might to adapt several things like the actual sending protocol (if different from SMTP) or the attributes hash contents.

Comment: Re "*you need to specify a SMTP session*", The question asked how to use `sendmail`, not SMTP.